# Наследование static полей

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
private:
    static int x;
};

int A::x = 0;

struct B: public A
{
    void foo() 
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }   
};
```

Почему выдаёт ошибку:

> [Error] 'int A::x' is private

?

Comment: Потому что private?)

Comment: У Вас ведь не в наследовании проблема, а в инициализации `int A::x = 0;` Инициализируйте в структуре А свою переменную

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, здесь проблема не в инициализации. Статические поля класса должны быть определены вне класса. Проблема в доступе к члену `x` из метода класса `B`. В классе `B` член `x` не доступен для прямого обращения, т.к. определён в классе `A` в секции `private`. Правильный ответ  от @Harry см. ниже.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `private` член доступен только классу и друзьям.

Чтобы он был доступен из `B`, он должен быть как минимум `protected`.